# View not updating on changing the view model in kendo ui web

Tags: kendo-ui, observable

I am using kendo ui web for one component, in this I have two level of arrays in the dataModel,
I have rendered successfully when on initial load, but when the change the viewModel of it is not updating the view.

Can any one help me here.

Comment: Please provide code and fiddle

Comment: This is my mistake. After building the component using view model, in UI the component dom structure got changed due to some third party plugin.By removing the third party plugin this issue is fixed.Thanks every.